# Nested for loop in Swift

Tags: swift

So I'm trying to see how many times my loops run with a test print statement.  My outer loop runs 5 times which is what I want.  The inner loop only runs 23 times instead of 25?  What am I missing?

```
  func currentLocation() -> GameLocation {

     for yValue in 0...4{

         for xValue in 0...4{

            let tempX = gameGrid[yValue].locations[xValue].x + 2
            print("x")
            let tempY = gameGrid[yValue].locations[xValue].y + 2
            if currentRowIndex == tempX && currentLocationIndex ==     tempY {
                return GameLocation(x: gameGrid[yValue].locations[xValue].x, y: gameGrid[yValue].locations[xValue].y, allowedDirections: gameGrid[yValue].locations[xValue].allowedDirections, event: gameGrid[xValue].locations[xValue].event) }
        }

    }
    return GameLocation(x: 0, y: 0, allowedDirections: [], event: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do you hit early return?

Comment: ah yeah that's it.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found the error. Since the chances are pretty low that this question would become useful to random site users looking for help, please consider deleting it. Good luck with your Swift project!